# Invariant factors of order 27000

Tags: group-theory

I am doing some practice problems to prepare for the exam and want to be sure I understand correct:

(1) Find invariant factors of abelian group $\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_{100} \times \mathbb{Z}_{45}$

My answer is: $3^2*2^2*5^2$ and $3*2*5$

(2) Let $p$ be a prime. Let $A$ be an abelian group of order $p^4$ that contains an element of order $p^2$. State all possibilities for the elementary divisors:

My answer is: 2 possibilities: $p^2, p^2$ and $p^2, p, p$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer for **(1)** is correct.

For **(2)**, note that we can list all abelian groups of order $p^4$ by looking at the partitions of $4$, which are
$$4,\ 3+1,\ 2+2,\ 2+1+1,\ 1+1+1+1$$
One should also note that if $G$ is a cyclic group with $|G| = n$, for each divisor $d$ of $n$, there exists a unique subgroup of $G$ with order $d$. Also, since that subgroup is also cyclic, its generators must have order $d$ as well. Can you revisit your answer for **(2)** now?